# Recursively copying a folder to an empty subfolder

Tags: wildcards, cp, recursive

How to copy all the content of the folder `/foo/bar`, which contains the file `/foo/bar/a` to an empty subfolder `/foo/bar/subfolder` without ending up with the file `/foo/bar/subfolder/subfolder/a`. Doing `cp -r * subfolder/` in `/foo/bar` does not work.

The system is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /foo
cp -Rp bar subfolder
mv subfolder bar
```

This avoids recursively creating a multitude of `subfolder/subfolder` directories on all Unix systems by creating `subfolder` alongside `bar` under `/foo`.  It creates the new folder by copying `bar` recursively.  The new directory is then moved into `/foo/bar`.

The sequence of commands could also have been

```
cd /foo
rsync -a bar/ subfolder
mv subfolder bar
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use

```
cp -r . subfolder/
```

instead, however, this still prints the annoying "cannot copy a folder to itself" to stderr.

Using `rsync` instead solves the issue,

```
rsync -r . subfolder/
```

Comment: Note that the both commands would create `subfolder/subfolder` and that if you're not using GNU `cp`, you may also get infinite number of subfolders under `subfolder` (infinite = until the pathname becomes too long).

Comment: Thank you for the note on GNU `cp`, I didn't know about it.